# python MySQLdb: use ssl without certificate

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-web-services, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I have a mysql server running on AWS which requires to authenticate via SSL (but does not require a user certificate).

## What I tried:

Connecting without a cert works fine via SequelPro (GUI):
[image]

It also works when using mysqlconnector with an empty ssl param: `'ssl_ca': ''`. But unfortunately not with MySQLdb.

I tried (using a connection string)

1.

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    con_str,
    connect_args={'ssl':{'ca': ''}})
pd.read_sql_query('select id from mytable limit 1', conn)
```

2.

```
conn = sqlalchemy.create_engine(
    # the following is used to enforce mysqlconnector usage
    con_str.replace("mysql:", "mysql+mysqlconnector:"),
    connect_args={'ssl_ca':''})
pd.read_sql_query('select id from mytable limit 1', conn)
```

The second works fine, the first not. Of course I also tried around with the bare connectors (`MySQLdb.connect()` and `mysql.connector.connect()`) and experienced the same behaviour and couldn't bring MySQLdb to work.

## Question:

Can you give me some hints on how to use SSL in MySQLdb without a cert (and key)?

## Further Background:

We switched to AWS from another provider so unfortunately no more ssh like before and now SSL. And I'm not administrating the DB so I can't make it using user certificates, am only being forced to use ssl without any certs.

A colleague explained that this is okay from a security viewpoint, because the server sends a cert. We trust him that he is the one belonging to the corresponding URL because we trust the CA.

Comment: Are you connecting to it from the same box? Is the MySQL instance publicly accessible? It's a bad idea to not use a cert in either of those cases.

Comment: No, I try accessing it from my local machine. The instance is not public accessible. I ran in this issue when moving from old hoster to AWS and now being "forced" to use ssl

Comment: If you are accessing it from your local machine then there is a chance that the machine you are talking to is not your mysql database. The purpose of the SSL cert is to ensure that you are in fact talking to your DB. Without it communication between you and the DB is not secure.

Comment: Yeah, I know. I'd prefer to use ssh like before, but this is not an option any more. And I'm not administrating the DB so I can't use user and server certificates, only being enforced to use ssl without cert. :-( Not happy with that too

Comment: @BaileyParker I changed the question, maybe now better?

Comment: @BaileyParker Do you have some ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 5):

Might not work in your case, but I was also looking to do this in pymysql, and it seems like passing a dict with any key works:

```
connect_args={'ssl': {'key': 'whatever'}}
```

But then I found out mysql-connector-python tries ssl even without any parameters. I switched because of another reason.

Comment: Underrated answer, it took me days to find this, thanks!